# Combination Counting puzzles me....

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A test has $6$ questions with $4$ possible answers for each (a,b,c,d), plus $5$ more true or false questions.
How many students are required to take the test to guarantee that $2$ write down the identical answers?

I was thinking it might be something like...
$$6C4\times 5C2=150$$

Is this the right line of thinking?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Must each question be answered? Can you give multiple answers for the same question (both `a` and `b` are true.) The question is how many ways are there to fill in the test. Then one more student is required to have a guaranteed duplicate.

Comment: Answers are all filled in and no multiple answers for each question.  I think the fellas below did a good job.

Comment: If you think they did a good job of answering your question, you might consider **accepting** the one you found most helpful. You can do that by clicking on the check mark next to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways can you answer the questions?
Think of it as flipping a coin; if you flip a coin $3$ times there are $2^3$ possibilities.
Therefore there are
$$4^6\times2^5=2^{17}$$
ways of answering your test.
In the worst case scenario, all $2^{17}$ students all have different answers. So when $1$ extra student is added, they must get the same answer to another student.
Thus we have
$$2^{17}+1$$
students needed to ensure $2$ identical answers.

Comment: Just wondering where the 1 is coming from for clarification?  I understand the other parts and appreciate it!  :D

Comment: @CaptainConfused I edited my answer, does it make it clear for you now?

Comment: Yeah thank you @EpicGuy!  I appreciate that greatly!  Have a great weekend!

Comment: @CaptainConfused No problem, have a good one too :)

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways the questions can be answered (assuming all are answered) is found as follows: The first 6 questions can be answered in 4 ways each, for $4^6$ ways in all. The 5 true-false questions can be answered in $2^5$ ways. So the number of different answer sheets for the exam is $4^6\cdot 2^5$. To guarantee two identical solutions, $4^6\cdot 2^5+1$ students are required.

Comment: Where is the 1 coming from just to clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: To guarantee that two students have identical answer sheets, there must be one more student than the number of different answer sheets that could exist. If there were only $4^6+2^5$ students, without the plus one, each student could have a different answer sheet.